# node path.extname returns empty string if no extension

Tags: javascript, string, file, path

when using path in node

```
path.extname(files[index])
```

I don't want it to return the empty string or if at all

using an if statement how would I only return those that have an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you are using this within a `map()` statement, there will always be a `return` value, or `false`. The easiest thing to do will be to just `filter()` the results:

```
files.map(file => path.extname(file)).filter(ext => ext !== '');
```

---

Note that arrow functions are available from node.js v4, if you're using an earlier version, replace them by

```
files.map(function (file) {
    return path.extname(file);
}).filter(function (ext) {
    return ext !== '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - was just running through some stuff.